# java hibernate criteria lock db2 table when its reading by someone

Tags: java, hibernate, db2, locking, criteria

Good day,

My code is as follow (I am usinig `org.hibernate.Criteria`) :

```
Criteria criteria = getSession( ).createCriteria(
                JSNumber.class );
        criteria.add( Restrictions.eq( "paymentDate", mnight ) );
        JSNumber result = (JSNumber) criteria
                .uniqueResult( );
```

This will return me an Integer from database.

After get the value, I will update the number by +1:

```
int newNo = result.getRunningNo( ) + 1;
            result.setRunningNo( newNo );
            getSession( ).merge( result );
            getSession( ).flush( );
```

Doing +1 is because my this number unique again in next time when trying to get the value again.

However, I have 1 problem:
When the time is almost the same, just within millisecond , two request to get result/update from/to this table, it may return same result for both's user request.

For example,
First request at `14:47:36.735` and Second request at `14:47:36.737`
First request get value = 110, and it will update it to 111.
But before first request update the value, second request already get the value, which is 110 also.

Any ideas to lock the table to prevent other request access to this table.

Answer (score 1):

If you adjust your number-generating process to use a database [sequence](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-identity-sequence-and-table-sequence-generator/) object in the DBMS, it will guarantee that every request will obtain a unique number, no matter how quickly the next request arrives.